# How do I use different partials and layouts in subfolders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, partials

I need to use a single partial for anything inside my `views/admin` folder. My setup:

```
/app/views/
        + admin
            + accounts
            + users
        + layouts
            - application.html.slim
        + application
            - _header.html.slim
        + users
        + accounts
```

I have a partial called `_header.html.slim` in `/views/application/`. The partial is rendered from `/views/layouts/application.html.slim`.

I want to render a different `_header.html.slim` partial for anything under the `/views/admin` dir. I can create a new `_header.html.slim` and add it to `/views/admin/accounts` and `/views/admin/users`, but I don't want to repeat my self. I want a single partial for everything under `admin`.

How can I so this? I tried adding `/views/admin/application` and `/views/admin/layouts` folders hoping they would override the ones in the `/view` dir, but no luck.

Comment: Can you not just create that partial somewhere (an app/views/admin_partials folder?), then reference that partial from all the admin views? render :partial => 'admin_partials/partialname'

Comment: See this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance

Answer (score 2):

layouts/application.html.slim:

```
- if controller.controller_name == "admin"
    == render :partial => "admin/header"
- else
    == render :partial => "application/header"
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's one hell of an ugly solution. There has to be something better. I believe I found it in template inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the folders themselves don't control which ones get run or applied - the folder structure is really just to help you organize it in a way that makes sense.

You could accomplish what you're looking for in a couple of ways, depending on your needs:

One way is to specify the layout (which includes the desired partials) in the controller, using the `render :layout => 'some_layout_name'` option [as outlined here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) (skip to the heading "2.2.11.2 The :layout Option" for the specifics).

Another way is to set a variable in your action that contains, say, the name of the layout(s) or partial(s) you want to render, and in your view do something like:

```
<% if @custom_partial == "slim" %>
  <%= render :partial => 'header.html.slim' %>
<% end %>
```

So, either specify a custom layout (if you want the whole layout including partials to be custom), or set a flag variable that controls which partials get rendered at which time, and use that variable to control the flow of rendering in your view. Which of those options is right for you depends really on which is cleaner, most reliable, and makes sense for your project; that is, it's up to you to decide.

Comment: First solution might be outdated, second might is damn ugly. There is a better way to do this using template inheritance. I just found it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance